# Adding more than 1 id to search for in SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Hey all i am in need of some ideas on how to go about doing the following:

I have a textbox that a user can type in an ID to search for in a database. It currently just checks for 1 ID.

Example:

```
User types in ID 645378
```

The Query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM blahTable WHERE theID = '645378';
```

Now, i am looking to allow the user to type in more than 1 ID at a time and display those results.

So again an example would be:

```
User types in ID(s): 645378, 78664, 901524
```

And now this is where my question comes into play. How can i create a query based on how many ID's the user inputs into the textbox?

Any help would be great!

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM blahTable WHERE theID IN (645378, 78664, 901524);
```

Note that if your values are actual strings and not numbers, then it will require some additional work:

```
    Dim asValues As String()
    Dim sbQuery As New System.Text.StringBuilder(5000)

    ' Get the text, but remove any embedded semi-colons and single quotes for sql injection'
    asValues = Miles.Text.Replace(";", " ").Replace("'", " ").Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    sbQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM blahTable WHERE theID IN (")

    Dim fUseComma As Boolean

    ' Add each value to the query string. In this case, we are wrapping with '
    For Each sValue As String In asValues
        ' Test the value for reasonableness (example only)'
        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
            ' Only use the comma starting from the second valid item added
            If fUseComma Then
                sbQuery.Append(",")
            Else
                fUseComma = True
            End If
            sbQuery.Append("'").Append(CInt(sValue)).Append("'")
        End If
    Next

    sbQuery.Append(")")

    cmd.CommandText = sbQuery.ToString
```

Comment: How can i do this without using the -1? I already check to make sure the user puts something in the textbox at first.

Comment: @StealthRT: See revised answer

Answer (score 4):

You could use the IN statement in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM blahTable where theID in ('123','456','789')
```

I would advise implementing this via a parametrized query to avoid Bobby Tables (SQL Injection)

Answer (score 1):

try this thing.

```
    Dim xIDList As String = "645378, 78664, 901524" 'the user should separate ID by COMMA 
    Dim xID() As String = xIDList.Split(CChar(",")) 'splits the xIDlist
    Dim xIDforQuery As String = String.Empty
    For Each oID As String In xID
        If oID.Trim.Length <> 0 Then
            xIDforQuery &= "," & " '" & oID & "'"     ' if ID is not numeric
            ' xIDforQuery &= "," & oID.ToString      ' use this line if ID is numeric
        End If
    Next

    xIDforQuery = xIDforQuery.Trim
    xIDforQuery = CStr(IIf(Mid(xIDforQuery, 1, 1) = ",", Mid(xIDforQuery, 2, xIDforQuery.Length - 1), xIDforQuery))

    Dim xFinalQuery As String = String.Empty
    xFinalQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM blahTable where theID in ({0})", xIDforQuery)

    '  xFinalQuery is the final query statement but this approach is vulberable to SQL Injection.
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the example as well, john.

Answer (score 0):

How do users know which ID's they want? If there aren't too many ID's, using a multiple-selection list-box would improve the UI and simplify the code. If there are too many, then you might consider using an auto-complete text-box for users to choose items that can then be copied (removed) from a list-box to be used by the query.